# I'm trying to code a standalone browser window using Python PyQt5. The window appears, but displays nothing. Please check my code and tell me why?

Tags: python, html, browser, pyqt5, widget

I am a novice Python hobbyist who is creating my own desktop application. I want the application to have an embedded web browser alongside some other widgets (text boxes, sliders, etc.). To start learning how to do this, I borrowed the code below from a [GeeksForGeeks tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-simple-browser-using-pyqt5/). I copied and pasted this code with no modifications and ran it in both Eclipse and IDLE. Both IDE's had the same result of an inert browser window ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4c98.png)).

Why won't the custom browser display any HTML? Further, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Maybe a different library than PyQt5? I tried using a combination of TKinter and Selenium, but it was super janky. Thanks in advance.

```
###                                                      ###
# Credit to @rakshitarora from GeeksForGeeks for this code #
###                                                      ###

# importing required libraries
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys
 
# creating main window class
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
 
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 
 
        # creating a QWebEngineView
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
 
        # setting default browser url as google
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
 
        # adding action when url get changed
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
 
        # adding action when loading is finished
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
 
        # set this browser as central widget or main window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
 
        # creating a status bar object
        self.status = QStatusBar()
 
        # adding status bar to the main window
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)
 
        # creating QToolBar for navigation
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
 
        # adding this tool bar tot he main window
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
 
        # adding actions to the tool bar
        # creating a action for back
        back_btn = QAction("Back", self)
 
        # setting status tip
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")
 
        # adding action to the back button
        # making browser go back
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
 
        # adding this action to tool bar
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)
 
        # similarly for forward action
        next_btn = QAction("Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")
 
        # adding action to the next button
        # making browser go forward
        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)
 
        # similarly for reload action
        reload_btn = QAction("Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")
 
        # adding action to the reload button
        # making browser to reload
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)
 
        # similarly for home action
        home_btn = QAction("Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)
 
        # adding a separator in the tool bar
        navtb.addSeparator()
 
        # creating a line edit for the url
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
 
        # adding action when return key is pressed
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
 
        # adding this to the tool bar
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)
 
        # adding stop action to the tool bar
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")
 
        # adding action to the stop button
        # making browser to stop
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)
 
        # showing all the components
        self.show()
 
 
    # method for updating the title of the window
    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("% s - Geek Browser" % title)
 
 
    # method called by the home action
    def navigate_home(self):
 
        # open the google
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
 
    # method called by the line edit when return key is pressed
    def navigate_to_url(self):
 
        # getting url and converting it to QUrl object
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
 
        # if url is scheme is blank
        if q.scheme() == "":
            # set url scheme to html
            q.setScheme("http")
 
        # set the url to the browser
        self.browser.setUrl(q)
 
    # method for updating url
    # this method is called by the QWebEngineView object
    def update_urlbar(self, q):
 
        # setting text to the url bar
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
 
        # setting cursor position of the url bar
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)
 
 
# creating a pyQt5 application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
# setting name to the application
app.setApplicationName("Geek Browser")
 
# creating a main window object
window = MainWindow()

 
# loop
app.exec_()
```

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808010/pyqt5-qwebengineview-causes-the-whole-window-to-go-white-blank) solves your problem.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for responding. I checked out the post and I understood it to mean I needed to set some environment variables. I set QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS with a value of "--no-sandbox" and QT_OPENGL to a value of "angle", but neither solved the problem.

'export QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--no-sandbox"' didn't work in IDLE.

Comment: @AgentFoxtrot I have tried to run your code and at least for me in works. It shows the webpage. The thing is that take so much time (around 15-30s). Furthermore, google.com doesn't work at least for me, but if you try with another url (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/) it works.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123321/qwebengine-view-loads-webpage-slowly) that maybe could help